# Is it possible to build an MsTest project into a self-contained executable? How?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I can do so using MbUnit framework, but I cannot force everyone to install it (please do not ask); everybody already has mstest.exe as well as the library.

http://www.gallio.org/oldwiki/MbUnit/TestExecutionUsingSelfExecutableTestAssemblies.html

We do not even run unit tests yet, so the easiest way to cram it in is to reuse an existing project. If it gets harder than that, then we will likely not have a test coverage for a while.

Looking forward to gaining some faith in MS Test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run MSTest without Visual Studio. It is designed to run using the IDE or using a Build server that had Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Galio and other tools can. Just because it is meant to be used by paid-only MSFT0only tools, does not mean that open source / 3rd party cannot help. For instance:

"""At present Gallio can run tests from MbUnit versions 2 and 3, MSTest, NBehave, NUnit, xUnit.Net, csUnit, and RSpec.  Gallio provides tool support and integration with AutoCAD, CCNet, MSBuild, NAnt, NCover, Pex, Powershell, Resharper, TestDriven.Net, TypeMock, and Visual Studio Team System."""

Comment: @hamishgrubijan That is not MSTest, I think they use an MSTEST simulator or some sort of hack.

Comment: Hm ... I guess I have used `MsTest` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` interchangeably. Sorry for confusion. But then again, `MsTest.exe` looks like a stand-alone app http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(VS.80).aspx and takes lots of command-line args, so in a way it is probably meant to be hack-able.